# ECMA 6, React Native and Redux: what does this syntactic sugar mean?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, react-native, redux

Lots of question I came up with while looking at an [react native redux example](https://github.com/alinz/example-react-native-redux) project. Can anyone point me to a document where those advanced syntactic sugar will be explained?

For instance:

```
import React, { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
```

Why is AppRegistry in {}, and what is the functional difference to the import of React and the import of AppRegistry?

What happens with this import-statement:

```
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';
```

Will they be imported as an array?

Another thing:

```
  render() {
    const { state, actions } = this.props;
    return (
      <Counter
        counter={state.count}
        {...actions} />
    );
  }
```

What will be passed to the Counter-Component? and where are the actions-variable came from? it is destructed from this.props, but in the caller nothing will be passed. Also: the spread operator in

```
<Counter/>
```

, will this append another arguments as they would passed with comma separated variable names?

Another thing:

```
export default function counter(state = initialState, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.INCREMENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        count: state.count + 1
      };
```

What does the return-statement really return? The spread operator and a property called "count", will they be merged together, if the spread-operator already contains a variable called "count"?

Also, the project contains a simple file called index.js in the reducers folder with the following plain content:

```
import counter from './counter';

export {
  counter
};
```

Does it make sense?

I'm asking because this project is named as example application for using redux in react native, but i think it is to completed for learning purposes. And i am not sure, if everything makes sense here on the structure. But my really question is to clarify these syntactic sugar elements i found there

Comment: this should prob be two separate questions, to your first one read the docs on import here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: i still dont get the difference between both variants in "import React, { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';".

Comment: its right there, above the example on your importing everything as types,

Comment: Search for default and named imports / exports.

Comment: same as:  var React = require('react-native').default, AppRegistry = require('react-native').AppRegistry;

Comment: @delete and to clarify, that is  "exports.default" and "exports.AppRegistry" contained inside "react-native" which should be inside your node_modules folder

Comment: I'm the author of that project. This project is mainly designed to target those who know basic and intermediate ES6. react and react-native are both simple but requires you to know some concept of ES6 and ES7. I suggest you to studying ES6 and ES7 by using https://babeljs.io/repl/. once you comfortable with concept go back to my project and look into it. If you have any question. just create an issue and I will gladly clarify it for you. Cheers

Comment: @Ali wow, thats great. Thank you very much! I caught up in between but good to know your offer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a lot of questions; most of them have nothing to do with React/Redux; they're really about EcmaScript 2015/2016/next. Maybe you'd like to re-phrase your question? Anyway, here's my two cents':

> Why is AppRegistry in {}, and what is the functional difference to the import of React and the import of AppRegistry?
>
> What happens with this import-statement:

Here's a little explanation about [ES2015 imports](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-imports). Consider two files:

```
// A.js
export default 1;
export const two = 2;

// B.js
import one from "./A";
import { two } from "./A";
console.log(one); // 1
console.log(two); // 2
```

This is (roughly) executed like:

```
// A.js
module.exports = {
    default: 1,
    two: 2
};

// B.js
var one = require("./A").default;
var two = require("./A").two;
```

You will notice that in ES2015, *curly braces* can be used in the import statement to denote that you only want to *import a specific export, but not the whole module*.

If you omit the curly braces, you will only import the *default* export.

You can also use *asterisks* to *import all exports* (that is the default export and all other named exports) into one binding. For example,

```
import * as everything from "./A";
```

should more or less be transpiled to:

```
var everything = require("./A");
```

Now, `everything` is an object with bindings to every export as seen above.
Thus, `everything.default === 1` and `everything.two === 2`.

> What will be passed to the Counter-Component?

Only `state.count` and an argument list of all `actions`.

> What does the return-statement really return?

The object

```
{
    ...state,
    count: state.count + 1
}
```

contains an [object spread property](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread). Assuming `state` is

```
{
    a: 1,
    b: 2
}
```

it will transpile to:

```
{
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    count: state.count + 1
}
```

> Also, the project contains a simple file called index.js in the reducers folder with the following plain content […]
>   Does it make sense?

Importing modules just to export them *can* make sense in projects where the internals shouldn't be imported directly. I haven't had a look at this particular project, so I'm not in the right place to judge whether this makes sense in this project or not; anyway, there's a [shorter syntax for that](https://github.com/leebyron/ecmascript-export-default-from), too:

```
export { counter } from "./counter";
```

Comment: thank you very much! i understood quiet better now

Answer (score 2):

I dont know of we should ask question like that on Stackoverflow, cause mostly it indicates you are still learning both ES6, and React, and you are not asking about a specific issue.

Anyway to get started quickly you will need to understand ES6, and React, and I would recommend to get started here:

**[Learn ES6 with Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/)**

**[React Simplified](http://blog.andrewray.me/reactjs-for-stupid-people/)**

P.S: ignore the title from andrew ray blog, his post is really great.

Comment: sidenote for ES6 newbies this could be a good starting point after a quick search on Google, so it has some inherent value.  just probably not so much as a question or answer

Answer (score 1):

brief summary in code form:

```
// the same:
let { propertyName } = { propertyName: 1, otherPropertyName: 2 };
var propertyName = { propertyName: 1, otherPropertyName: 2}.propertyName;


import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';
var types = require('../actions/actionTypes');
// where "types" is set to the "exports" object in actionTypes.js


// essentially "spreads" or merges all of state's values into the object
let obj = {
    ...state,
    count: state.count + 1
};
var obj = _.merge( state, {count: state.count + 1 } );  //underscore merge
var obj = Object.assign( state, {count: state.count + 1 } );  //ES6 Object.assign function for merging
// for loop merge objects
var obj = {};
for ( var x in state ) if (state.hasOwnProperty(x)) obj[x] = state[x];
obj.count = state.count + 1;
```

For `CounterComponent`, it just merges the `actions` object into its CounterComponent's props.
It's basically same as:

```
//spread version
CounterComponents({
  counter: state.count,
  ...actions
});
//underscore merge
CounterComponents(_.merge({
  counter: state.count,
}, actions));
//es6 merge
CounterComponents(Object.assign({
  counter: state.count,
}, actions));
```